# How do I generate a javascript alert if the record already exists OR if it does not exist in a PDO MySQL insert query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL DB that I would like to insert data from a PHP form using PDO connect.

Is there a way to have an Javascript alert popup when;

1. a record already exists or
2. it has been added because it doesn't exist

I am using this code;

```
$dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $category = $_REQUEST['category'];
     $sql = "INSERT INTO category (category) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$category."') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT category FROM category WHERE category = '".$category."') LIMIT 1;";
     $sql = $dbo->prepare($sql);
     $sql ->execute(
        array(
           ':category'=>$category
           )
        );
```

Thank you for helping a newbie (I looked for an existing answer but nothing seemed approriate).

Comment: You should at least specify how this PHP code communicate with your client-side part. It is from an AJAX call, or do you output the HTML later on ?

Comment: Set the category `column` in your table to be `UNIQUE`.

Comment: I guess you don't see that you're talking about client-side system from the server-side...

Comment: @hjpotter92 I just ran ALTER TABLE  `category` ADD UNIQUE (
`category`
)

Comment: @Maskime I am a newbie and trying to understand

Comment: Why is there a need for a minus 1, I was very specific, cant I just ask for help without having to be told I am rubbish for asking in your non technical way?

Comment: @johnD This is what I'm pointing out. You're talking about generating an alert -> this happens on the client side. The code you're showing is on the server side. You need to understand the difference between the 2 to be able to come up with a solution. Do you have a clear vision of what happen from the moment you type an URL in your browser until the content is display in your browser ? (You need to look into this)

Comment: @Maskime i think he does understand that, he just wants to know how to display a javascript alert based on the two criteria he listed.

Comment: @Edward, yes!, thank you edward (can I have the +1 now?)

Comment: @JohnD Ok my bad. have you try to put a '''try {} catch(){}''' block and see what happens ?

Comment: Doesn't mean i'm going to be any help haha, i would do it the same way as you did but using the new mysqli. Fetch the data, check it against your criteria and then do an `alert('//error here');`

Comment: actually its quite simple, just get the affected rows, that will be the basis of your alert message

Comment: @Maskime could you give me an example please?

Comment: what does happen in your current query when that entry exist? does it still insert?

Comment: @Ghost It inserts fine when it doesnt exists and when it exists it doesnt, so all is well. Just need an alert what it has done or refusing to do

Comment: It is not advisable to use javascript inside PHP. Better opt for another way like using ajax request. That would be the right option.

Answer (score 2):

Actually its quite simple. Just check the affected rows thru `->rowCount()`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO category (category) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$category."') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT category FROM category WHERE category = '".$category."') LIMIT 1;";
$stmt = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':category'=>$category));

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // inserted
    echo '<script>alert("Insert Complete!");</script>';
} else {
    // did not insert
    echo '<script>alert("Record already exists!");</script>';
}
```

Depending on how things are setup on your codes right now, this is closest thing you can get to alert the status of your insertion.

Of course, if you're using an ajax to actually request this insertion, you can just respond with a boolean, then just present it on the client thru the success block of your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $category = $_REQUEST['category'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO category (category) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$category."') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT category FROM category WHERE category = '".$category."') LIMIT 1;";
 $sql = $dbo->prepare($sql);
 try {
 $sql ->execute(
    array(
       ':category'=>$category
       )
    );
 catch(Exception $ex) {
     print_r($ex);
 }
```

Since you've add the constraint on your field to be unique and ask PDO to handle error with exception, PDO should raise an exception when trying to insert the data if it's already in DB.
Instead of `print_r()` you can do `echo "alert('My error message');"`

Comment: I tried yours and it doesnt like  the line 'catch(Exception $ex) {'

Answer (score 0):

Example, this needs to be converted to PDO to answer the question.

```
// $link = mysqli_connect blah blah

function check_exist($link, $cat) {

    $query = "SELECT `category` FROM `category` WHERE `category` = '$cat'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_query($link));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_num($result);

    if(count($row) >= 1) {
        <script>alert('Row already exists!');
    } else {
        insert_record($link, $cat); //fire the insert function
        <script>alert('New record added!');
    }

}

function insert_record($link, $cat) {
    $cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $cat);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `category` (`category`) VALUES ('$category')";
    mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_query($link));
}
```